# OPENCART change the price when the size change

Tags: php, twig, opencart

i want to make the price of the product change when the costumer change the size , every size of the clothes has his own price 
im working with opencart cms

Comment: Hi, what have you tried? show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find and use live option price module. Something like this: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=26328&filter_search=live%20price&filter_license=0